# Using the ASP.NET thread-safe cache object with an almost read only object

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, thread-safety

I was using the cache object to hold an XMLDocument object.
To be specific, the code is:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
if (HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("AuthorizationXML") == null)
{
    string file = GetAuthorizationXmlFilePath();
    xDoc.Load(file);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("AuthorizationXML", xDoc, new CacheDependency(file));
}
else
{
    xDoc = (XmlDocument)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("AuthorizationXML");
}

return xDoc;
```

Anyway, my team leader suggested that because cache object is thread safe, it will a waste to use it for an almost readonly object and it will be better to implement the cache object as a singleton free threaded object on application object.
It this statement sounds legit? 
Does thread-safe means that cache object is implemented with locking, will it slow the system? 
Is locking even applied when just reading from cache?
I'd appreciate any comment.

Comment: Your code has a race condition: The cache item might be non-null when you first check it, meaning you go into the `else` clause, by which time the item might have disappeared from the cache.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not counting on it to change to null, it is supposed to be loaded once and no code set it to null, just read from it.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET only guarantees thread-safety around changing an item in the cache, but does not give any guarantee when changing an object it holds in the cache. So if the object you retrieve from the cache isn't immutable (=unable to change after creation), the ASP.NET cache will *not* protect you.

Objects that are *not* immutable should *not* be reused by multiple threads. It doesn't matter if you store it in the ASP.NET cache or some globally defined variable. Reusing mutable objects over threads is dangerous, and can lead to race conditions, in case they are (accidentally) changed.

When the object is immutable, it doesn't matter where you store it, since all threads can use it without any danger. The choice over using Cache or Global/Singleton has nothing to do with the thread-safety of an object, since both require thread-safe objects and the guarantees of the cache are pretty lame, so this doesn't help you.

The ASP.NET cache allows you to keep an item in the cache for a period of time, while a Singleton will (per definition) stay there until the AppDomain dies. So if you need the item to be refreshed more than once per AppDomain lifetime (which you show with your example by the use of the `CacheDependency`), than you something else than a Singleton; such as the ASP.NET cache.

Comment: I sounds like the concern of the OP is not ensuring that the object is accessed safely, but rather on performance.  If the cache is only allowing one reader at a time, and the app is only ever reading the variable then lots of threads will be waiting when there is no real reason for them to wait.  If, however, the cache is implemented with a smart reader/writer lock then this becomes a non-issue.  The OP's question is which locking mechanism is used and how will it perform with lots of concurrent reads.

Comment: Thanks Servy, you got me, that's exactly what I'm aiming at.
Thank you also Steven, I'm using CacheDependency but very little chance of the XML to actually change, it's just for safety. Also as far as I know cache IS implemented as singleton so no choice there, it will be a singleton anyway, I'm just curious if there will a performance issue with that and in general if thread-safe = locking, does .Net implement it like this.
BTW, is there a way for me to make sure an object is immutable? I'd love more responses about the performance issue.

Comment: I can say I'm reasonably sure that if there is locking around the Cache that it uses a reader/writer lock, not just a straight mutex.  Additionally accessing the cache is so quick that the time the lock is held should be fairly low.  However those are just educated guesses, and I have no references, hence the lack of an actual answer.

Comment: @Tomer: If you're worried about potential performance problems then you should profile *your app* to see if there are actually any issues. (I would guess that the cost of retrieving the XML document from the cache would be tiny compared to any subsequent processing that you might do with it.)

Comment: @Servy - Thanks, I suspect you are right, I just want to be sure, in order to be convincing... Thanks also LukeH.

Comment: @LukeH True, but the one problem with this particular type of issue is that it will perform just fine with one (or a small number) of concurrent users.  If there are problems, it would come with hundreds or thousands of concurrent users. Some websites don't need to support this, and some do. While it's possible to stress test, it's just not as reliable (or as mean) as many real life cases end up being at exposing code that doesn't scale well.

Comment: @Servy: That's very true, but the ASP.NET cache has been extensively tested in the field by thousands of large sites - if it didn't perform well then there'd almost certainly be thousands of people saying so. Of course, we're not in a position to say whether it'll work well for the OP, but it certainly wouldn't be where I'd be looking for potential performance improvements.

Comment: @Servy: The ASP.NET Cache itself will hardly be the problem here. Parsing that XML document will most likely be the bottleneck. ASP.NET Cache reads are not much more than (lock protected) dictionary reads.

Comment: I agree with the both of you.  One can deduce that it shouldn't be a problem for both of those reasons, but it won't be demonstrated by profiling the application, since you won't likely be replicating production stress.  I said several replies ago that I highly doubt this would be a problem.  The only question that remains is "can any of us prove it, rather than just guessing"?